# Better way to ignore exception type: multiple catch block vs. type querying

Tags: c#, .net, exception

There are situations that we like to ignore a specific exception type (commonly `ObjectDisposedException`). It can be achieved with those two methods:

```
try
{
    // code that throws error here:
}
catch (SpecificException) { /*ignore this*/ }
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle exception, write to log...
}
```

or

```
try
{
    // code that throws error here:
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is SpecificException) { /*ignore this*/ }
    else
    {
        // Handle exception, write to log...
    }
}
```

What are the **pros and cons** of this two methods (regarding **performance, readability**, etc.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say it's a matter of preference mainly, but the dedicated emtpy catch looks cleaner to me. Programmers reading your code can be assumed to be familiar with try/catch constructs, and they expect you to sort your catch blocks from specific to general. The usual way people read try/catch constructs is to skim through the catches until they find one that matches what they're looking for (just like the compiler does), and then see what it does. The reader is doing this anyway, so when you have a dedicated empty catch for that exception type, it is immediately obvious that it is a special case and that you're discarding the exception. The built-in type checking logic, OTOH, requires the reader to find the more general exception branch, which is probably way down the list of catch blocks, and then read through the actual logic to find out what happens. I'd say this requires far more reading effort than an empty catch.

Another point is that you're supposed to have a good reason for ignoring exceptions; with an empty catch block, it will be immediately obvious to you and anyone who reviews your code that you are ignoring errors, which is good - it means people will notice and be a bit more conscious about such a potential gotcha, and you'll be pushed toward adding a comment that explains why you're doing it. If you bury the ignore-this-exception part inside the handler logic, people might read past it and then wonder why their exception doesn't pop up anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
catch (SpecificException) { /*ignore this*/ }
```

is about as explicit as one can get—but only if you include the comment to ensure it is clear this isn't a case of forgetting to fill in the handling code.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something along the lines of the second style but will encapsulate the actual logic in another method:

```
try
{
    // code that throws error here:
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ExceptionHandling.Handle(ex);
}
```

And internally would check for the type

```
if (ex is SpecificException) { /*ignore this*/ }
else
{
        // Handle exception, write to log...
}
```

1. IMO it is more readable.
2. You don't repeat the handling logic
3. If you will ever need to handle ObjectDisposedException it would be easy enough to change

Thanks,
E

Comment: What if you need to rethrow some exceptions without losing their stack trace?

Comment: True. But I think it would be safe to say the 99.9999% of the applications out there do not need their stack trace other than logging purposes.

Comment: I failed to explain that you can still log this information without a problem (The information will be presented either as part of the exception StackTrace property, or the InnerException.StackTrace Property) It is the other 0.0001% applications out there that will have a problem with this design.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer the first style as it is more readable and it suits better when you make different decisions for different exception types.

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (IgnoreThisException) {
    // ignore this
} catch (UnableToHandleHereException) {
    throw; // this should be catched by caller
} catch (Exception e) {
    // log the rest
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the first is clearly better.  It is the normal method for catching multiple exceptions provided by the language.  It also maps directly onto two catch blocks in the CIL, while the second requires an `isinst`.

I don't know whether this will concretely improve performance, but it should be easier for the JIT to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

The second style is better because you are *ignoring* an exception. It communicates intent better than the first style.

If another developer saw the first style, he/she will wonder if you forgot to write code that handles the ignored exception.

In terms of performance, there will be no noticeable difference.

Comment: even if you weren't ignoring that exception but wanted to handle SpecificExcpetion differently from other exceptions, the first piece of code is still preferable from a readability standpoint while performance-wise is similar.

Comment: I would prefer the first style as I find it more readable. Why someone would think that the implementation has been forgot when there is a comment "/* ignore this */"?

Comment: What?  They both have explicit `/*ignore this*/` comments.  I don't see how anyone could think the writer of the first one forgot.

Comment: This is *exactly* what the whole exception handling syntax is for - filtering exception types, from specific to general, and doing the right thing based on the type of the exception.

Comment: I chose the second style bearing in mind that in a team with many developers, code comments often do not reflect the actual implementation. I think it's wrong to rely on a comment to communicate a developer's intent on something as important as ignoring a particular exception.

Comment: Either way, with no comment, I'm going to wonder why the block is empty.  I don't think the second is self-documenting at all.

Comment: I agree with Matthew. If the comments were removed, the second would have empty if block. How well does that communicate the developer's intent? Presuming that someone will even notice that there is an empty if block... Empty catch block is easy to see and the intention is much more clear.

Comment: I think Matthew is right too. The first style is a better style overall, but I also think the second style better communicates "I want all exceptions to be handled by this catch-all block except this one exception". If it's coded as if(!(ex is specificException)){ ... }, then there's no doubt the developer is ignoring that exception.